# Display list of all fieds in using a metaclass

Tags: python, django

Since I have 561 fields in a class, could we use a metaclass to help me displaying a list of all fields in this class?

Here is what I have done so far :

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class EmployerProfile(AbstractAddress):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomerProfile, verbose_name=_('Customer'),
        related_name='employerprofile')

    company_name = models.CharField(_('Company name'),
                                    max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = PhoneField(_('Phone'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_extension = models.CharField(_('Extension'), max_length=10,
                                       blank=True, null=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(_('Job title'), max_length=50, blank=True,
                                 null=True)
    date_hired = models.DateField(_('Date hired'), blank=True, null=True)
    supervisor_name = models.CharField(_('Supervisor name'), max_length=50,

...
                                       blank=True, null=True)
    has_missing_fields = models.BooleanField(_('Has missing informations'),
                                             default=True)
    manual_validation = GenericRelation(ManualFieldValidation)
```

Here is a function I would like to modify in using a metaclass

```
def clean_fields(self):
        if income_source != 'Employed':
            to_empty = [
                "company_name",
                "job_title",
                "date_hired",
                "supervisor_name",
                "phone",
                "phone_extension",
                "civic_number",
                "street",
                "address_line_2",
                "city",
                "state",
                "zip_code",
                ...
            ]
            for field_name in to_empty:
                setattr(self, field_name, None)
        super(EmployerProfile, self).save(*args, kwargs)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post what you have attempted so far.

Comment: @James It's done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the field names of a model like this:

```
field_names = [f.name for f in EmployerProfile._meta.get_fields()]
```

or if you want field instances simply do:

```
field_inst = EmployerProfile._meta.get_fields()
```

Inside your model you can do it like this:

```
class EmployerProfile(AbstractAddress):
    # model fields

    @classmethod
    def field_names(cls):
        return [f.name for f in cls._meta.get_fields()]
```

Comment: I am a bit familiar with this method, but do I have to create a meta class inside my class. Could you modify function to use this method?

Comment: So, you're saying that you want to view the model field names from inside a `Meta` class?

Comment: No, not exactly. I thought I would need to create a metaclass to use `field_names = [f.name for f in EmployerProfile._meta.get_fields()]`.

Comment: No, you don't need to create a `Meta` class for that.

Comment: Maybe it is a silly question, but I'd like to know if I have to write juste `income_source`, `customer.income_source` or ... `customer(income_source = income_source, ...)`?

Comment: I think it should be `self.customer.income_source`, but I don't quite get what you're asking here!